# Force post slug to be auto generated from title on save

Tags: slug, title, save-post

I'm running a property site where many properties are sold in apartment blocks.

Because of this what the content editors do is create a post/property with all the details and then use a duplicate post plugin to create the others.

Each time they duplicate a post/property they change the title to reflect the property number and maybe change a few bits of meta data E.G price.

What they forget to do is wipe out the slug and let a new one be generated from the title. Here is an example slug from the first property entered:

`merle-court-plot-50-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh`

but then when they duplicate the slugs become:

```
merle-court-plot-50-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh-2
merle-court-plot-50-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh-2-2
merle-court-plot-50-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh-2-2-2
merle-court-plot-50-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh-2-2-2-2
etc
```

But when they change the titles the slugs would be better like:

```
merle-court-plot-51-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh
merle-court-plot-52-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh
merle-court-plot-53-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh
merle-court-plot-54-182-carlton-vale-nw6-5hh
etc
```

So my question:

> How do I force the slug to be re-generated on post save, after they have updated the property title?

The slug for this CPT should always be auto generated, there is never a need to manually set it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest workaround could be:

```
function myplugin_update_slug( $data, $postarr ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
        $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'myplugin_update_slug', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: Does `wp_insert_post_data` get fired on post update too? The post has already been created by the duplication process. The slug needs changing once the post is updated with the correct title.

Comment: NVM I found the answer to that comment: `A filter hook called by the wp_insert_post function prior to inserting into or updating the database.`

Comment: Yes, it does. Whenever you create or update a post, this filter will be fired.

Comment: I've attached to the if statement a check to make sure I'm on my post_type too.

Answer (score 8):

Also, run the slug from `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` through [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) to ensure that it's unique.  It will automatically append '-2', '-3' etc. if it's needed.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of replacing spaces you should use the build in function [`sanitize_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) which will take care of the replacing for you.

Like this:

```
sanitize_title( $post_title, $post->ID );
```

Also, you should use a unique slug. Which you can get with the function [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug)

So putting it all together a solution might be:

```
function myplugin_update_slug( $data, $postarr ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
        $data['post_name'] = wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] ), $postarr['ID'], $data['post_status'], $data['post_type'], $data['post_parent'] );
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'myplugin_update_slug', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Your change to the accepted answer is very important. It should probably be added to it as an edit though.

Answer (score 3):

Something I've had bookedmarked for a little while is the following (yet untested),

[Source LINK](http://ostedesign.com/automatically-change-post-slug-and-permalink-when-editing-wordpress-title)

```
//add our action
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 11, 2 );

function my_save_post($post_id, $post){

   //if it is just a revision don't worry about it
   if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
      return false;

   //if the post is an auto-draft we don't want to do anything either
   if($post->post_status != 'auto-draft' ){

       // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
       remove_action('save_post', 'my_save_post' );

      //this is where it happens -- update the post and change the post_name/slug to the post_title
      wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' => str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['post_title'])));

      //re-hook this function
      add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post' );
   }
}
```

Comment: In that code surely the re-hook is not needed and even if it was it would need the priority and args set to 11 and 2? Also instead of `str_replace()` would `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` be more suitable?

Comment: By calling `wp_update_post` function, you will call `wp_insert_post` function, which fires `save_post` action. You will get infinite loop.

Comment: @EugeneManuilov - but in the code the hook is removed so not to loop infinitely...

Comment: @Brady ah... yes I see. My fault.

Comment: Thanks for the **down vote**. @Brady I agree that `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` would be more suitable in that it is a function provided by WP. So wherever possible, swap out regular PHP functionality with WP functions. Although, both would work. As this is not my code, I have not tested it.

Comment: @EugeneManuilov If you down-voted this answer, please reverse your vote. The reputation points are not of my concern, however the fact that this remains a plausible answer is and as such down-voting this answer provides a disservice to potential readers by misinforming them that this function will loop infinitely when it will not. Also this snippet provides commentary through out which will give those who lack the understanding a better chance at seeing whats happening at each stage of the function. They can apply this knowledge and understanding to your snippet also.

Comment: @userabuser yes, i was trying to do it, but my vote is locked and your post have to be updated (edited) before I can reverse it back. As soon as you edited it I will revert my down vote back.