# Editing does not change post_name

Tags: post-meta, urls, title, post-editor

Suppose I wrote an article, "My Article Title", it has been saved into the database with `$post_name=my-article-title` , and the permalink is `mysite.com/my-article-title`. All good.

Now, if I didn't like the title and change it to "Title of my article", I expect the post name and the url change accordingly. So the url should become `mysite.com/title-of-my-article`, however, it remains as `mysite.com/my-article-title`. So how do I set it to change?

Should I add a meta box somewhere? Or is there a plugin for this?

Thanks !

Comment: do you mean you want it to change automatically? you can change it manually by clicking the permalink field (or the edit button) while editing the post.

Comment: If you want to do it automatically you can try this solution http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52896/force-post-slug-to-be-auto-generated-from-title-on-save

Comment: @Milo yes, I found that out just now :) If you want, post it as an answer.