# How to update permalink on the fly?

Tags: permalinks, filters, title, actions, slug

So, Wordpress automatically generates the slug/permalink on the fly based on the post title after you click away from editing the title. Is there an action/filter hook for me to change those on the fly?

Like, for example, if the title is "How to update permalink on the fly?", normally the slug would be "how-to-update-permalink-on-the-fly", but instead I want it to be "update-permalink-fly-1005364" (no propositions and added post ID).

I know the slug is generated in the post.php somewhere but I don't want to modify core file.

Please help and thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force post slug to be auto generated from title on save](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52896/force-post-slug-to-be-auto-generated-from-title-on-save)

Comment: That's almost true, but I need it to fire when the post_name/slug/permalink is created, not when the post is updated.