# How to hook into permalink when publishing-saving post?

Tags: permalinks, filters, hooks

I want to know how I can change the structure of the permalink to my desired one before saving or publishing my post in Wordpress?
For instance, when I add the title like `the wordpress blog` in my post I get the permalink structure similar to the below:

```
http://localhost/2015/09/10/the-wordpress-blog/
```

I want to change it to something like below before saving  or publishing it:

```
http://localhost/2015/09/10/the-wordpress-blog-is-mine/
```

But I don't know hook what into what to achieve my goal.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52897/4771

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found my answer on my own.

```
//add our action
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 11, 2 );

function my_save_post($post_id, $post){

   //if it is just a revision don't worry about it
   if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
      return false;

   //if the post is an auto-draft we don't want to do anything either
   if($post->post_status != 'auto-draft' ){

       // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
       remove_action('save_post', 'my_save_post' );

      //this is where it happens -- update the post and change the post_name/slug to the post_title
      wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' => str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['post_title'])));

      //re-hook this function
      add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post' );
   }
}
```

Comment: This function looks like it is doing what WordPress already does when it auto-generates the slug based on the title; simply replacing the " " with "-". The only thing the WordPress one does is run it through strtolower().

Comment: @belinus The answer you gave is really superfluous since it is addressing something which is obvious. The function above can be improved a little bit to work as I intend.

Answer (score 0):

Underneath the Title field is the slug field. Normally WordPress will automatically create a slug base on what you are typing in the Title field. All you need to do is type in what you want that to be and then publish.

Comment: I am aware of the slug field in the post page of the Wordpress, I am looking for a way to filter the slug after the post is saved. I want to programmatically modify the slug to my own desired format.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the structure then? Because in your examples, you merely change the content.